How to make an first use of abbreviation be expanded in a footnote (glossaries-extra)?
I am using several closely related abbreviations, all of which are first used in the same paragraph. I'd like the first one to be expanded in the text (short-long), but the others to use the short form in the text and the long form in a footnote. According to the glossaries-extra manual (4.5.1.2.7. Footnote Styles), the short-footnote format should do the trick, but I seem to be doing it wrong, according to the non-working example below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries[abbreviations]
\newabbreviation{foo}{FOO}{a regular abbreviation with a long form}
\newabbreviation{bar}{BAR}{Another abbreviation, but because of where I first use \texttt{\textbackslash gls} I would like the long
  form in a footnote for bar}
\begin{document}
The first time I use \gls{foo}, it should show both the long and short form in the text.  The second time, \gls{foo}, it should not.  Fine!

But I'd like to use a footnote here: \gls[format={short-footnote}]{bar}. This is not because of the abbreviation itself, but dependent on the context in which it is first used.

\printabbreviations
\end{document}


The format is clearly wrong. That takes as value the name of a command (without backslash) and applies that to the page number in the list of abbreviations.
I do not think that you should change abbreviation styles on the fly (when I tried it with \setabbreviationstyle the package warned me, things can go wrong). So probably your best bet is to separate (there is perhaps a dedicated command in the package but I didn't try to find it)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abbreviations,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries[abbreviations]
\newabbreviation{foo}{FOO}{a regular abbreviation with a long form}
\newabbreviation{bar}{BAR}{Another abbreviation, but because of where I first use \texttt{\textbackslash gls} I would like the long
  form in a footnote for bar}
\begin{document}
The first time I use \gls[format=textbf]{foo}, % to show the bold number
it should show both the long and short form in the text.  The second time, \gls{foo}, it should not.  Fine!

But I'd like to use a footnote here: \glsxtrshort{bar}\footnote{\glsxtrlong{bar}}. This is not because of the abbreviation itself, but dependent on the context in which it is first used.

\printabbreviations
\end{document}


